# Why does fixed positioning not work with flex on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

I have a sidebar on my site that is hidden on smaller screens. When a user clicks a button it opens.

The content of the sidebar is long so it needed to be scrollable. I achieved this using:

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

I am also using flex so the sidebar also has these rules:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
```

The sidebar displays well in all browsers except when viewed on older iOS devices (chrome or safari) running iOS 9. The problem with these is that the content overlaps - it seems that the height of the fixed div is ignored.

[Here is a jsfiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/xxo6gawu/9/)

If I remove `position: fixed` from the demo it displays fine in iOS. Alternatively, if I remove flex settings it also displays fine. It seems to be a combination of the two.

What I've tried:

- `height: auto` `min-height: 100%` `max-height: 100%` `height: 100vh`
- `bottom: 0`
- `position: absolute` // this won't scroll

If there is no CSS solution to this problem, it is OK to check if an ios device is being used and apply a separate stylesheet?

Any advice much appreciated.

HTML for completeness:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="block">
   text content...
  </div>
<div class="block">
   text content...
  </div>
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to detect ios using:

```
/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream)
```

and then changing the sidebar css to `display: block`

It isn't ideal, and I still don't understand why iOS has problems combining fixed and flex...